# If two closed subschemes $Z_1,Z_2 \subseteq Z$ are isomorphic over an extension of the base field, does this imply $Z_1 \cong Z_2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Z$ be a scheme over a field $k'$. Let $\Omega/k'$ be a field extension. Let $Z_1, Z_2$ be closed subschemes of $Z$ such that $Z_1 \times_{k'} \Omega = Z_2 \times_{k'}\Omega$ (as closed subschemes of $Z \times_{k'}\Omega$).

Let $U:= \operatorname{Spec}A$ be an affine open subscheme of $Z$. Then $(Z_1\cap U) \times_{k'} \Omega = (Z_2 \cap U) \times_{k'}\Omega$ ?

In fact, I want to show

> Let $Z$ be a scheme over a field $k'$, let $\Omega / k'$ be a field extension
> and let $Z_1, Z_2$ be closed subschemes of $Z$ such that $Z_1 \otimes_{k'}
> \Omega = Z_2 \otimes_{k'} \Omega$ (as closed subschemes of $Z\otimes \Omega$).
> Then $Z_1 = Z_2$.

This question is local? And will this statement true? If not, when? How about the case when $Z$ is finite type over $k'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** In fact, I want to show

> Let $Z$ be a scheme over a field $k'$, let $\Omega / k'$ be a field extension
> and let $Z_1, Z_2$ be closed subschemes of $Z$ such that $Z_1 \otimes_{k'}
> \Omega = Z_2 \otimes_{k'} \Omega$ (as closed subschemes of $Z\otimes \Omega$).
> Then $Z_1 = Z_2$.

**Answer:** Let $A:=\mathbb{R}[t]$, $Z:=Spec(A)$ and let $Z_1:=V(t^2+1), Z_2:=V((t-1)(t+1))$.
It follows  $A_1:=A/I_1 \cong \mathbb{C}$ and $A_2:=A/I_2 \cong \mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$. There are isomorphisms

$$ A_1\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C} \cong A_2\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$$

but $A_1 \neq A_2$ are not isomorphic.

**Question:** "This question is local? And will this statement true? If not, when? How about the case when Z is finite type over k′?"

**Answer:** The rings $A,A_i$ are finitely generated $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.

Comment: Wow..from some point of view, it is bad news:) (Originally that question was posed for constructing some glued scheme. It seems that I should think different method.) Anyway thanks !

Comment: @Plantation - when you extend the base-field a scheme may change from being reduced/irreducible/... to being nonreduced/reducible/.... The above isomorphism is defined over the complex numbers but does not "come from" the real numbers - it does not "descend".

Comment: Thanks for editing the title more properly ~

Comment: @Plantation - it is a natural question and other students may ask the same question - whenever you ask something on this site - take care when formulating the question and try to explain the notation and your definitions. Then others may benefit as well.

Comment: O.K. I will. Thanks for advice.~